# Text goes outside JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, word-wrap

I am trying to do something in Java which requires me to have a JTextArea in a ScrollPane.

Here is how I have defined them:

```
private JTextArea longestparagraph = new JTextArea();

....
JScrollPane scrollpanedreapta = new JScrollPane(longestparagraph, 
                        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
                        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scrollpanedreapta.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Cel mai lung paragraf:"));
```

The problem I'm encountering is that the text doesn't start on a new line when it reaches the right border of the TextArea but it continues. Got any ideas how to solve that? Here's a picture to make my statement a little bit clearer.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer. Just had to this:

```
longestparagraph.setLineWrap(true);
longestparagraph.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Comment: have to set column and row too (JTextArea(int, int))