# How can I make this JEditorPane display the way I want?

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, jscrollbar

It starts off displaying like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eztip.png]

Then as expected, when you fill it with text beyond the bottom limit it looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPbbv.png]

But the text trails off the side a bit, which definitely has something to do with the horizontal scroll bar it activates, but it looks really weird. So how can I disable the horizontal scroll bar and have the text display cleanly without it trailing off to the right a bit?

```
JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(editorPane);
    editorPane.setLineWrap(true);
```

editorPane.setLineWrap(true); does not work, it says "The method setLineWrap(boolean) is undefined for the type JEditorPane" If there's a way to use HTML in a JTextArea tell me; but I don't think that'll work. I need to be able to add HTML later.

Full code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MainGUI {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainGUI window = new MainGUI();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public MainGUI() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
//  frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setBounds(500, 200, /*W*/600, /*H*/435);
//  frame.setSize(/*W*/600, /*H*/435);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 564, 337);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(editorPane);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(10, 365, 564, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
}
```

}

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074549/text-goes-outside-jtextarea. You're probably looking to `setLineWrap(true)` on your `JTextArea()` object. Line wrap means the words will go to a new line when the end of the horizontal white space is used up. However, this will split words in the middle of them and fill up as much white space as possible. `setWrapStyleWord(true)` means that it won't cut the words in half when wrapping to the next line

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: Reopened the question since you confirmed you do need to use a JEditorPane to display HTML. However I doubt you will get an answer until you post an `MCVE`. This may just be a JEditorPane problem since it is highly unsual to have a continuous string of data the is thousands of lines long. The question why would you ever display this using HTML?

Comment: `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the editor pane contains HTML, the natural behavior is to wrap when it gets to the maximum width. The trick is to tell the scroll pane not to display a horizontal scroll bar, so it suggests to the view component to limit the size to whatever width it is (damn well) given by the view.

E.G. (an actual MCVE)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainGUI {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    private String[] loremIpsum = {
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ut nulla egestas arcu rhoncus molestie. Mauris eget consequat sem, a accumsan eros. Praesent sem massa, dignissim sit amet porta ut, interdum sit amet ligula. Pellentesque cursus odio vel vestibulum vulputate. Donec facilisis ex sed pellentesque laoreet. Praesent ut sem id lectus suscipit pulvinar. Mauris a eros dui. Nulla ultrices est eu lacinia sagittis. Vivamus ac erat sit amet dolor ultricies euismod. Curabitur condimentum in ante id mattis. Pellentesque non sagittis diam. Nulla dapibus lacus sagittis turpis vehicula, vitae eleifend odio euismod. Sed elementum facilisis nisl. Donec lectus nulla, rutrum ac sollicitudin pulvinar, tempus ut arcu. Maecenas ut vulputate purus. In luctus cursus magna sit amet facilisis.",
        "Morbi vitae dictum enim, quis porttitor elit. Nam quis accumsan leo, id rhoncus tortor. Praesent tellus magna, ultrices quis nulla vel, fringilla ultricies purus. In hendrerit volutpat elit a posuere. Duis scelerisque, sapien eu faucibus eleifend, lectus lacus interdum diam, sed bibendum orci est ut urna. Quisque a sem iaculis ex aliquam tempor. In id dictum ex, non gravida lacus. Integer neque mauris, tristique eu ultrices quis, tristique pellentesque nunc. Donec egestas tristique dolor, ac sagittis ante elementum non.",
        "Mauris sit amet ullamcorper erat. Nunc non condimentum augue. Vivamus et odio eget massa convallis vulputate nec ut lacus. Donec sapien dolor, facilisis sit amet venenatis sit amet, suscipit ut nisi. Praesent vitae lorem lacinia orci volutpat fermentum. Nullam dolor erat, facilisis vitae volutpat id, feugiat et augue. Nunc congue, lectus a vehicula lacinia, est libero volutpat quam, nec maximus ante mauris eu urna. Etiam nunc dolor, auctor et orci vitae, pulvinar pretium orci. Nam et est rhoncus, pharetra mauris id, condimentum leo. In fermentum non urna sed imperdiet. Cras sit amet nulla eget purus convallis accumsan. Donec dictum eget magna pulvinar scelerisque. Fusce efficitur nisl sed nibh vestibulum laoreet.",
        "Morbi tincidunt eleifend nisl. Nullam libero massa, imperdiet vitae egestas eu, sodales ac lacus. Donec eu commodo dui. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean vel diam volutpat, gravida quam vitae, tristique dui. Cras aliquet gravida massa eget lobortis. Donec ullamcorper eu purus eget iaculis. Ut id leo erat. Etiam iaculis ante eu mi molestie suscipit.",
        "Quisque dapibus consectetur mauris eu faucibus. Etiam ac varius odio. Nulla non elit velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus est leo, ultricies quis sem ut, euismod vestibulum augue. Donec auctor eu nisi a aliquam. Integer libero sapien, fringilla ac posuere ut, malesuada ut leo. Maecenas ut ante non arcu molestie gravida nec eu neque. Vivamus elit nisi, auctor at luctus eget, accumsan id dolor."
    };

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainGUI window = new MainGUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MainGUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("HTML in editor pane");
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        //frame.setBounds(500, 200, /*W*/ 600, /*H*/ 435); this is guessing!
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
                "<html><body style='width: 400px;'>");
        for (String s : loremIpsum) {
            sb.append("<p>");
            sb.append(s);
        }
        JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
        editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
        editorPane.setText(sb.toString());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(
                editorPane, 
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
                // this is an important line!
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER); 
        editorPane.setCaretPosition(0);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        // it should be the correct size needed to display the content,
        // but now let's make it half that height.
        Dimension d = frame.getSize();
        d = new Dimension(d.width, d.height/2);
        frame.setSize(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is that text suposed to say?

Comment: @SamuelFinzhry Which 'text' & written by who? Please quote it (or at least part of it).

Comment: @AndrewThompson The "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" gobbledegoop.

Comment: Search on 'Lorem ipsum'. Why is it relevant?

Comment: And "//frame.setBounds(500, 200, /*W*/ 600, /*H*/ 435); this is guessing!" what is guessing?

Comment: I took a look at 'Lorem Ipsum'; very interesting, I didn't know there was a name for that. As for why I asked, I was just curious.

Comment: *"what is guessing?"* The required size and location. Note that my example explicitly sets neither, though it does suggest a width for the HTML (then bases the height on a proportion of the final width in order to display a scroll bar).